# NetworkAvailabilityChanged event not firing in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've got a serious problem with windows phone 8 not detecting changes in network state.

I have tried subscribing to the following:

```
DeviceNetworkInformation.NetwrokAvailabilityChanged
```

but the event won't get fired. How can I get the network changes? Anybody please help me with this.

Here is my code:

```
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += DeviceNetworkInformation_NetworkAvailabilityChanged;
        }

        private void DeviceNetworkInformation_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Availabilty Changed"); 
        }
```

Thank you.
Deepak

Comment: Can you edit your question and let us know how you subscribe to this event? Maybe your syntax is the problem.

Comment: Now I have the code with my question.

Answer (score -1):

Try running your Message box code in the UI thread, instead of the main thread where it checks for the Connectivity change.

```
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Availabilty Changed"); 
        });
```